# How to check if sequence exists in Fluent Migrator

Tags: c#, .net, oracle, fluent-migrator

Is there any way to check if sequence exists before create in `Fluent Migrator`?

here is my code:

```cs
IfDatabase("Oracle").Create.Sequence("SEQ_TEST").MaxValue(1).MaxValue(99999).StartWith(1).IncrementBy(2);
```

error:

> ORA-00955: name is already being used by existing object tips

I can check tables using this code:

```cs
Schema.Table("TableTest").Exists()
```

But i dont know how i can check sequences, is there any way?
Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Resolved my issue using SQL Command

```cs
            Execute.Sql(@"
                DECLARE
                  VAR_SEQUENCE_EXIST VARCHAR(1);
                BEGIN

                  SELECT COUNT(1)
                    INTO VAR_SEQUENCE_EXIST
                    FROM USER_SEQUENCES
                   WHERE SEQUENCE_NAME = 'SEQ_TEST';

                  IF VAR_SEQUENCE_EXIST = 0 THEN       
                    -- Create sequence 
                    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'create sequence SEQ_TEST
                                        minvalue 1
                                        maxvalue 9999999999
                                        start with 1
                                        increment by 1
                                        nocache';
                  END IF;
                END;");
```

Answer (score 0):

SEQUENCE is a oracle reserved word, it may be the problem.

Comment: the word i used was an example, i edited my question